# Read out variables stored in mysql database with Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the ID of my users.

I want to print out his name and family on the page.

For example:
There are a lot of users in my table,

The ID is saved as user_id in a Post table.

Now I want to show the name and family of the user selected by the user_id in Post table.

Does anyone know how to do this in Laravel 5.3
All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should try and understand the basics of Eloquent: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::find(user_id);
```

Now you have the concrete user, so you can "play" with it's fields.
Example:

If you want to get the user's `name` (and you have a 'name' field in your db and model) you should use it like this:

```
$user->name
```

Just a tip: Learn some Eloquent, if you want to use Laravel, before asking questions like this.

I hope it could help!
Good Luck!

Comment: i have user_id in a foreach : @foreach($datas as $key=>$value)
   <tr>
  <td>{!!++$key!!}</td>
                <td>{!!$value->user_id!!}</td>
         @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

OK i solve it with a function :

```
function userIdToUserNameConvert($id){
$user = App\User::find($id);
echo $user->name .' '.$user->family ;
}
```

and in foreach i use it :

```
<td>{{userIdToUserNameConvert($value->user_id)}}</td>
```

and it is work correct.